# What is the difference between stack buffer overflow, stack underflow and stack overflow?

Tags: data-structures, programming-languages, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

My teacher from data structures mentioned it during our lectures today when studying stack, but didn't give proper explanation to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between a stack overflow and buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stack-overflow-and-buffer-overflow)

Comment: Related: [How can a stack underflow happen in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552141/how-can-a-stack-underflow-happen-in-c) (there are some C++-specific details, but overall it should be understandable and generalisable to other languages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, stack and buffer are different things as you may know.

The **buffer overflow** happens when a program (any kind) tries to write beyond the allocated memory that it has. Imagine

```
int myArray[5];
myArray[9]=3;
```

**Stack overflow** is a specific case. When running, for example a recursive function, the stack which had a reservation already, keeps growing to be bigger than the original reservation!

```
void recurse()
{
int numbers[20000];
    recurse();
}
```

This will never end. Each function call creates a new stack frame and the stack will eventually consume more memory than is reserved for it.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120575/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stack-overflow-and-buffer-overflow) for more detail!

And **stack underflow** it is similar to the buffer overflow. With this example you'll understand it!

Imagine you have a list, and you are popping elements.

*I assume you know what popping is, but in case you still haven't done that in your subject, it basically is taking out elements. Depending on the type of structure, it will take them from one side or another!*

Imagine a list called `List`contains three numbers: `[1,2,3]`. I'll write it like this: `List => [1,2,3]` Which means "List contains [1,2,3]".

```
List => [1,2,3]
List.pop => [2,3] //List.pop now contains (->) [2,3]
List.pop => [3]
List.pop => []
List.pop => ??? Stack underflow!
```

Comment: And what is stack underflow?

Comment: Just added it, because I did not see the edit! Look at the answer now! @Corina If the answer was useful and with effort, remember to upvote it! If it solved your problem, mark it as an answer! ^^

Comment: What is the difference between   .   And ->?

Comment: In this case, I am using `->` to show what the list contains! I'll edit it to make it more clear! @Corina

Answer (score 2):

A buffer overflow is a very generic term describing a situation in which you have a buffer filled up with more elements than it should, leading to undefined behaviour.
Imagine that you have an array of 1024 bytes, to read 1kb from the network, and you attempt to place more into that.

A call stack overflow is a situation in which there's too many function calls (usually happens when you have unbounded recursion), where exactly because of the number of them, the computer tends to run out of memory for allocating too many stack frames (imagine every stack frame has a default size, about 2MB iirc in linux by default - if you get a call stack tree thousands of functions deep it's possible you'll run out of memory).